# Programmatic method to check and/or publish the the Google OAuth consent screen

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

We have a lot of Google Cloud projects along with OAuth consent screens and client IDs.

We are trying to avoid using just the Google Cloud console to check and publish OAuth consent screen with some programmatic method, such as APIs or even gcloud CLI.

On Google Cloud project, is there a programmatic method to check and/or publish the the OAuth consent screen?

Answer (score 0):

oAuth enables a 3rd party such as Google or Twitter to authenticate your user(s). That 3rd party owns their consent screen. If you want to own authentication, don't rely on a 3rd party for authentication in which case you can have complete control over the authentication process.

You have other options for authentication (from Google) such as Firebase's email link auth.